# Entity Framework not showing in Add New Item dialog anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I've just done a clean install of Windows 8 Pro and downloaded and installed *everything that I've previously downloaded and installed, before the clean install of Windows.* And now when I open an existing `Website` in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web (or create a new website) and right-click the App_Data folder > Add > Add New Item - ADO.NET Entity Framework Provider item used to show up, so I can add entity coolness to my site - but that's no longer an option.

I've just spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out what is going on, and so I tried reinstalling Entity again via the Nuget PackageManager Console:

Install-Package EntityFramework

as suggested on one of the MSDN pages, and it "successfully" installed, but there is not a shred of evidence that it exists anywhere on my system.

Why can't I add Entity Framework stuff to my websites anymore?

Answer (score 0):

EntityFramework is an assembly and it will be in packages\entityframework folder within your solution folder.

Comment: That's no use when I can't use Entity Framework from within Visual Studio. Why doesn't Entity Framework appear in any of the dialogs anymore?

Comment: What do you mean by "EF from within Visual Studio". You need a reference to that assembly, which NuGet will do it for you. And you can start using it.